# Casting while using the '==' operator

Tags: c, arrays

In my C program, I have a line where I am using the '==' operator, and the two operands are casted as char, like so:

```
char top_level_domain[sizeof(char) * 128];
...
if((char)top_level_domain[i] == ':' 
    || (char)top_level_domain[i] == '/')
```

Is this recommended/safe? If not, how should I go about checking the contents of a certain element in an array?

EDIT: added declaration and removed casts to the character literals

Comment: Please add the declaration of top_level_domain so that the type is known.

Comment: Depends on the type of `top_level_domain`, I guess. Aren't character constants like `':'` always of type `char`, i.e. casting the constant should not be necessary!?

Comment: At least the cast of `':'` is not needed. But we need more detail.

Comment: In C, a constant like `':'` is an `int`, not a `char` (in part because it would be automatically promoted to `int` in calculations).

Comment: I'm trying to understand why you are considering this specific code would be a candidate for casting at all. (and in order of your questions, no, you're doing it correctly if you *remove* the casts). If something like this doesn't compile without them, you probably have a significantly larger problem (like an outright incorrect data type comparison).

Comment: @WhozCraig: Sadly there's a sufficient amount of nonsensical C code (not to mention tutorials and books) out there that new C programmers get introduced to cargo-culting like this...

Comment: Is `char top_level_domain[sizeof(char) * 128];` really what you mean? You declare an array containing `sizeof (char) * 128` `char`s, not an array of 128 `char`s.

Comment: @JohnB: Well `sizeof(char)` is useless and also suggests ignorance of what `sizeof` means and how arrays work, but since the value is 1 it doesn't do any harm...

Comment: The array declaration with sizeof(char) is a serious WTF. What is that even mean? It's not malloc! For 2+ byte sized types you'd end up with a much larger array. @dsplayer14, please edit the code, if anyone sees it and starts using it you'll have caused a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In general, it is *more* safe and effective to avoid casting when you can, because it allows the compiler to perform type checking.  For example, spot the error:

```
// Let's pretend you forgot or mixed up the type here...
char **top_level_domain;
// ...
if ((char) top_level_domain[i] == (char) ':')
    ...
```

Or maybe...

```
char top_level_domain[sizeof(char) * 128];
...
// Whoops! forgot to type [i]
if((char)top_level_domain[i] == ':' 
    || (char)top_level_domain == '/')
```

Whoops! You forgot to dereference the pointer, you're getting garbage.  The compiler *would* have given you a diagnostic message, but since you used a cast, the diagnostic message is gone.

**Note:** This will actually cause a diagnostic message on some compilers because `char` is narrower than `char *`, but if we were using `size_t` instead of `char` then there would be no narrowing, but it would still be an error.

### Why use casts?

There are quite a few situations where the C "integer promotions" and "usual arithmetic conversions" can cause undesired behavior.  For example,

```
size_t align_to_16_bytes(size_t x)
{
    // return x & ~15u; // WRONG
    return x & ~(size_t) 15u; // RIGHT
}
```

However, in general it will only cause problems when you are using types wider than `int` or when you are mixing signed and unsigned types that are *at least* as wide as `int`.

Newer languages such as Java and C# largely avoid this problem by only allowing widening implicit casts.

Comment: +1 from me too. Your examples are much better than my abstract description of the problem.

Comment: Your last example does not make sense to me, could you explain it some more, please?

Comment: @dsplayer14: On systems with 64-bit `size_t` and 32-bit `int`, you need to be careful when you compute a `size_t` mask and use 64-bit arithmetic for the whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

The casts are "safe" but useless, and very bad style. Generally in C, anything that *needs* a cast is at best bad style, and more often, invoking undefined behavior, so the presence of casts in a source file is a "code smell" - an indication that the author probably did something wrong and that the reader needs to be extra careful looking for bugs.

Just remove the casts and your code will be perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

A cast is an explicit statement to the compiler that you want to override the default implicit type conversions (or account for the absence of them) that the language gives you. Generally speaking, these default implicit type conversions are well thought through by the language designers, and work *with* C's type safety, not *against* it.

A good example is `void *`, which, according to C11 Section 6.5.16.1.1, may implicitly be converted via assignment to or from "a pointer to any object type". This implies that you can *not*, for example, implicitly convert it to a pointer to a function. This is exactly how you would want it to work when calling `malloc()`, for instance - it *must* convert to some other type of pointer, since you obviously can't create objects of type `void`, but it makes no sense at all to dynamically allocate a block of memory for a function. Thus, the default implicit type conversions here do exactly what you'd want - let you convert to a pointer to any object type since that's the whole purpose, but loudly complain if you try to convert to anything else.

Some people seem to be of the view that casting the return from `malloc()` makes it "explicit" what you're trying to do, but (1) you never see those people doing things like `int i = 1; double d = (double) i;`, they seem to make a special case out of `malloc()`; and (2) it doesn't do this at all, since what the cast actually makes explicit is the fact that you want to override the type safety and default conversions that C gives you, when what you actually want to do in this case is to abide by them.

Alternatively, sometimes the implicit type conversions do *not* give you what you want, and a cast is necessary. The obvious example is integer division, which always gives you an `int`. The folks who made C *could* have provided another operator to perform floating point division with integers, if they wanted to, but they didn't, the result being that if you want to perform division with two integers and integer division is not what you want, then you have to cast one of them to a floating point type to override the default behavior to achieve what you want. If integer division *is* what you want in a particular case, then you obviously don't cast.

So, as a general rule, when C gives you the result you want without casting - which is most of the time - don't cast. Only cast when C's default behavior does not give you what you want, and you're willing to explicitly abandon the type safety it gives you as a result.

Answer (score 0):

The casts are unsafe, not only because of the compiler type checking issue that Dietrich Epp speaks about, but also because the reduction of the value range can lead to false positives:

```
int myValue = 'a' + 768;      //A number that is not equal to 'a'
assert(myValue != 'a');       //This is true...
assert((char)myValue == 'a'); //...but so is this!
```

Of course, this happens because I constructed myValue in a way to yield this false positive. However, 1/256th of all integers will compare equal to a specific character if the integer is casted to a char, which is a lot of possible false positives. This won't happen, if you allow the compiler to choose the integer representation for the comparison.